# How to use CSS transition effects

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I want to learn how to use css transition effects but I can't figure it out. I would like to add a transition effect like this one to my site http://themeforest.net/item/smiling-responsive-parallax-one-page-template/full_screen_preview/6185323 (check the portfolio section) but every time I try to add the fade transition effect it doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have the markup ready but I can't get the transition effect to work. Can someone please help me figure this out?

This is the markup I have.

```
<div class="home-photo-gallery">
<div class="gallery-item-wrap">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://realfood.tesco.com/media/images/juicehero-d2faf7ed-c433-4971-b1fc-b1ff7bf093fe-0-472x310.jpg" /></a>
    <div class="item-text">
        <h4>Orange</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.gallery-item-wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.item-text h4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.item-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 472px;
    height: 310px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.8);
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

.gallery-item-wrap:hover .item-text {
    display: block;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XNgV8/

Thanks in advance I really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't think these are CSS transitions. I would bet there is a lot of JS running at the same time to make it work and look that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS transitions for that. Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/XNgV8/3/

```
.gallery-item-wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.item-text h4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;    
}

.item-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 472px;
    height: 310px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.8);
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.gallery-item-wrap:hover .item-text {
    opacity: 1; 
}

.gallery-item-wrap:hover .item-text h4 {
    top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with `opacity`and `easing` in the right place. ;)

Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XNgV8/1/

(I hope this is the effect you were going for.)